# Facebook logout in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/)

for Facebook login. In this tutorial they are using custom Facebook login view. I have change the text and picture of Facebook login view. Now i need to call logout function from other class. In this tutorial they are handling logout function.I need to call the logout function. Any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the custom login control instead?

Facebook Developers site has good tutorials about it [site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1), check out the like, it is really easy to understand how to implement this